# How can I load only specific child object to a mapping place holder

Tags: jpa, inheritance, mapping

I have following object mapping in our project. One contact can have multiple quotes from typeA and typeB.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_ind_contact")
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Quote> quotes;

}
```

Abstract Quote class.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "app_code")
@Table(name = "t_ind_quote")
public abstract class Quote implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
    private Contact contact;

    @Column(name = "app_code", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int appCode;
}
```

TypeA Quote class

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class TypeAQuote implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

TypeB Quote class

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class TypeBQuote implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

This mapping is working fine for all operations. But for some operations we need the contact object with typeA quotes only. As of now, we will filter typeA quotes after system loads data from the database.

Is there a way that we can populate a contact object only with typeA quotes? I mean even the generated queries will load only typeA quotes.

Comment: No. And it is a bad idea: if I have client code calling method getQuotes() on contact then I expect it to return me all quotes- I should not expect to have knowledge that this particular Contact currently only has TypeA quotes loaded. Write queries to return the filtered info.

Comment: If you really need only A or only B then the best solution is  to try mapping them as separate collections.  `@OneToMany  private List<TypeAQuote> quotesA;` etc.